# Proof of Axiom of choice by well ordering

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am reading Folland's real analysis. In Prologue, proof of Axiom of choice using well ordering is as follows:

Let $X=\cup_{\alpha \in A}X_{\alpha}$. Pick a well ordering on $X$ and, for $\alpha \in A$, let $f(\alpha)$ be the minimal element of $X_{\alpha}$. Then $f\in \prod_{\alpha \in A}X_{\alpha}$.

My question is that why it is necessary to pick the minimal element of $X_{\alpha}$ so that we would need well ordering principle. Why can't we just choose an arbitrary element of $X_{\alpha}$ while we know that $X_{\alpha}$ is non-empty so it has at least one element.

I think I have not understood the axiom of choice well.

Comment: Because you cannot describe $f$ with a finite formula for arbitrarily many $\alpha$ by just saying “pick something”. That’s the essence of the Axiom of choice. As Bertrand Russell said: to pick one shoe from each of infinitely many pairs, I can just say “pick the left shoe”. But to pick a sock form each of infinitely many pairs of socks, I need some guarantee that the function exists, and that guarantee is given by the Axiom of Choice.  The well-ordering lets you say “always pick the left one”, while what you want is to describe how to pick a sock infinitely many times.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, if every $X_{\alpha}$ has exactly one element, then we would not need the axiom of choice to show that the cartesian product is non-empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose an arbitrary element of one $X_\alpha$ without using the axiom of choose. For that matter, you can choose one arbitrary element from any **finite** number of the sets $X_\alpha$ without using the axiom of choice. But to choose one member from each of an infinite family of sets you need either the axiom of choice or a specific algorithm for choosing them. Here the well-ordering on $X$ provides that algorithm: it allows to choose from $X_\alpha$ very specifically the minimal element of $X_\alpha$ with respect to the well-ordering of $X$. This is no longer an arbitrary choice: it is completely determined by the well-ordering.